# angular custom directive ng-show 2-way binding not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a `tag-comment` custom directive. it has 3 modes: `view`, `edit` and `create`.

This is my controller function for tag-comment:

```
    controller: function($scope) {

        $scope.userService = userService

        //view mode
        $scope.showViewMode = ($scope.mode === 'view')
        if ($scope.showViewMode) {
            $scope.showToEdit = (userService.isAtLeastCreator($scope.entity))
            $scope.showOnDelete = ($scope.onDelete() && $scope.entity.status !== 'deleted' && userService.isAtLeastCreator($scope.entity))
            $scope.showOnUndelete = ($scope.onUndelete() && $scope.entity.status === 'deleted' && userService.isAtLeastCreator($scope.entity))

            $scope.showMetaUpdate = ($scope.entity.status === 'normal' && $scope.entity.meta.updatedBy && $scope.entity.meta.updatedDate)
            $scope.showMetaDelete = ($scope.entity.status === 'deleted' && $scope.entity.meta.deletedBy && $scope.entity.meta.deletedDate)
            $scope.showMetaBan = ($scope.entity.status === 'banned' && $scope.entity.meta.bannedBy && $scope.entity.meta.bannedDate)

            $scope.displayNameCreatedBy = (userService.getDisplayName($scope.entity.createdBy))
            $scope.displayNameUpdatedBy= (userService.getDisplayName($scope.entity.meta.updatedBy))
            $scope.displayNameDeletedBy = (userService.getDisplayName($scope.entity.meta.deletedBy))
            $scope.displayNameBannedBy = (userService.getDisplayName($scope.entity.meta.bannedBy))

        }

        //edit mode
        $scope.showEditMode = ($scope.mode === 'edit')
        if ($scope.showEditMode) {
            $scope.showOnUpdate = $scope.onUpdate()

        }



        //create mode
        $scope.showCreateMode = ($scope.mode === 'create')
        if ($scope.showCreateMode) {
            $scope.showOnCreate = $scope.onCreate()
            $scope.showOnCancel = $scope.onCancel()
        }


    },
```

This is my html template:

```
<div class="tag-comment">

    <!--view mode-->
    <div ng-if="showViewMode">
        <div class="my-panel">

            <div class="my-panel-heading">
                {{entity.title}}
            </div>

            <div class="my-panel-body">
                {{entity.content}}
            </div>

            <div class="my-panel-footer">

                <button ng-show="showToEdit" ng-click="mode='edit'" class="my-button">Edit it here</button>

                <button ng-show="showOnDelete" ng-click="onDelete()(entity)" class="my-button-danger">Delete</button>
                <button ng-show="showOnUndelete" ng-click="onUndelete()(entity)" class="my-button">Undelete</button>

                <span>
                    created by <a href="/profile#!/{{entity.createdBy._id}}" class="my-link">{{displayNameCreatedBy}}</a>
                    at {{entity.createdDate}}
                </span>
                <span ng-show="showMetaUpdate">
                    updated by <a href="/profile#!/{{entity.meta.updatedBy._id}}" class="my-link">{{displayNameUpdatedBy}}</a>
                    at {{entity.updatedDate}}
                </span>
                <span ng-show="showMetaDelete">
                    deleted by <a href="/profile#!/{{entity.meta.deletedBy._id}}" class="my-link">{{displayNameDeletedBy}}</a>
                    at {{entity.deletedDate}}

                </span>
                <span ng-show="showMetaBan">
                    banned by <a href="/profile#!/{{entity.meta.bannedBy._id}}" class="my-link">{{entity.meta.displayNameBannedBy._id}}</a>
                    at {{entity.meta.bannedDate}}
                </span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--edit mode-->
    <div ng-if="showEditMode">

        <div class="my-form-group">
            <label for="edit_title">Title:</label>
            <input ng-model="entity.title" id="edit_title" placeholder="Enter Title" class="my-form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="my-form-group">
            <label for="edit_content">Content:</label>
            <textarea ng-model="entity.content" id="edit_content" class="my-form-control" placeholder="Enter content" class="my-form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="showOnUpdate" class="my-form-group">
            <button ng-click="onUpdate()(entity); mode='view'" class="my-button-success">Update and Done</button>
        </div>

    </div>


    <!--create mode-->
    <div ng-if="showCreateMode">

        <div class="my-form-group">
            <label for="create_title">Title:</label>
            <input ng-model="entityInfo.title" id="create_title" placeholder="Enter Title" class="my-form-control"/>
        </div>
        <div class="my-form-group">
            <label for="create_content">Content:</label>
            <textarea ng-model="entityInfo.content" id="create_content" class="my-form-control" placeholder="Enter content" class="form-control"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="my-form-group">
            <button ng-show="showOnCreate" ng-click="onCreate()(entityInfo)" class="my-button-success">Create</button>
            <button ng-show="showOnCancel" ng-click="onCancel()(entityInfo)" class="my-button">Cancel</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see, there are 3 `div`s, `view`, `edit` and `create`. user can switch between `view` and `edit` mode. When user click `Edit it here` button, I simply set `mode = 'edit'`. But the UI is not updated.

I have tried directly using `<div ng-if="mode === 'view'">`, it works. But I prefer to put all the `ng-show/hide/if` toggles in controller in case the condition gets more complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried doing something similar in the past, but the issue you're seeing is that the scope variables for showing modes (for example, `$scope.showEditMode`) won't be automatically updated based on another variable being updated (`$scope.mode`). That's what `$watch()` does.

You could create a function like this that would update both the mode and the show mode variables:

```
$scope.setMode = function(mode) {
   $scope.mode = mode;

   $scope.showEditMode = ($scope.mode === 'edit');
   $scope.showViewMode = ($scope.mode === 'view');
   $scope.showCreateMode = ($scope.mode === 'create');
}
```

You could then call it from your button clicks like this:

```
<button ng-show="showToEdit" ng-click="setMode('edit')" class="my-button">Edit it here</button>
```

Hope that helps. Best of luck!

Comment: what about initial mode before user switch? do i need to call it in controller first?

Comment: Yeah, going this route, you'd want to have it set on the controller load. I changed the function to setMode in my example to make it more clear. You would just replace wherever you're initializing the scope variables with $scope.setMode('view'), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so my idea would be to move all your logic into a service which is returning the values you need depending on the mode the user selects

The example Service

```
.service('ModeService', function ($http, Ls) {
    return {
        ReturnViewValues: function (Mode) {
         var Obj = {};
        if (Mode == 'view') {
            //put your Controller Logic here
            Obj.Value1 = your logic
        } else if (Mode == 'edit') {
            //put your Controller Logic here
             Obj.Value1 = your other logic
        }
        return Obj;
    },
```

In your Controller i would simply make 1 Function which is called from all ng-clicks

```
$scope.changeMode = function(Mode){
   $scope.ViewObj = ModeService.ReturnViewValues(Mode)
   //now your ViewObj contains all the info you need for the active View

}
```

And in Your HTML i would recommend to use

```
<button ng-click="changeMode('edit')">Edit</button>
<button ng-click="changeMode('view')">View</button>
```

I would also recommend you to create your html a little bit more dynamic so you only need 1 HTML block you can use ng-class / and ng-clicks where you change the functionality depending on the mode

Cheers